# Flash not working on all domains

Tags: flash, joomla3.0

I'm facing a weird problem with a flash movie (.swf) embedded in a site. Not quite sure if it is a joomla related problem. First of all, I've got a site on two different domains (griller.at, griller.mx). On the .at domain, everything is working fine. On the .mx domain, in czech and spanish, the top-banner-swf isn't displaying. But it is displaying on the other two languages with the same code.

http://www.griller.mx/es/

http://www.griller.at/es/

Here's the code how the flash file is included:

```
<object id="FlashID" width="645" height="130" data="images/flash_en/slideshow.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <param name="movie" value="images/flash_en/slideshow.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!--[if !IE]>--><img class="mceItemObject mceItemFlash" src="http://localhost/griller/components/com_jce/editor/tiny_mce/plugins/media/img/trans.gif" width="" height="" data-mce-json="{" object="" :="" type="" application="" x-shockwave-flash="" data="" http:="" www="" griller="" at="" images="" flash_en="" slideshow="" swf="" 645="" 130="" />
  <div><img src="images/flash/1.jpg" alt="Banner" /></div>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going directly to the flash file does not work, either:
http://www.griller.mx/images/flash_en/slideshow.swf

This suggests

- It is not a Joomla issue
- It is not a html embedding issue
- Your file may be corrupt - try uploading it again
- You may have uploaded it as ASCII instead of binary
- It may be a server issue, eg the mime type `application/x-shockwave-flash` may not be enabled

Comment: The problem is, that the english version (and the whole .at domain) use the same webspace and file. And if you take a look there (http://www.griller.at/images/flash_en/slideshow.swf) it is working. So no file issue. Only possible solution is a server issue, but as it is working in other languages, it cant be such an issue too.

Comment: The other languages are using an absolute URL and pulling it from the .at address - ie http: //www.griller.at/images/flash/slideshow.swf - only the Spanish one is trying to call it from .mx via a relative URL /images/flash_en/slideshow.swf - the absolute URL should fix it.  I imagine why this is probably is a server configuration thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a brief comment. Why do you use the flash in such a well-made site - flash can not be displayed on iPhones and iPads, but there are free extensions that can display the same. Alternatively, you can create a gif animation

Comment: I tried to tell that to my customer a while ago, but they do love their flash-animation from the previous site. Now we have just an image fallback.

Comment: You Can still do exactly the without flash, so thye won't mis anything

Comment: I know, but they don't want to pay my work when I'm building a non-flash version :)